# TSQL Self Join: Exclude consecutive ID records having set criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
ID, DATE, STATUS
1, 01JAN2012, STOP
1, 04JAN2012, RESTART
2, 01JAN2012, STOP-1
3, 10JAN2012, STOP
4, 15JAN2012, RESTART
5, 01JAN2012, STOP-1
5, 04JAN2012, STOP-2
5, 10JAN2012, STOP
5, 15JAN2012, RESTART
```

Expected Output:

```
ID, DATE, STATUS
2, 01JAN2012, STOP-1
3, 10JAN2012, STOP
4, 15JAN2012, RESTART
5, 01JAN2012, STOP-1
5, 04JAN2012, STOP-2
```

I want a SELECT statement to exclude all records with same ID having (STATUS='RESTART') and one consecutive previous record, if available.

Comment: I don't think that your explanation of what you want matches your expected output, why are the record with ID = 5 on those results?, and the ID = 4?

Comment: I think id = 5 rows are expected because he said he wants to exclude one consecutive previous record (if available) along with restart record, but id = 4 row should not be in result set according to OPs condition.

Comment: @rs. - I son't what "one consecutive previous record" means here. And OP also said the s/he wanted to exclude "all records" with same ID with the one whith `STATUS='RESTART'`, so I figure that the records with ID = 5 shouldn't be there

Comment: when i read it again, i see what you are saying, you are right. This question and expected results are very confusing.

Comment: @Lamak - My understanding is that each group of records with the same `id` should be treated separately.  Then, within each group, exclude all `RESTART` records *IF* they have a preceding record based on the `DATE` field, and also exclude *that* preceding record.

Comment: @Dems - You are probably right. Though it may need verification from op.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what would happen if there were two consecutive RESTARTs, but barring such complications I think you might want something like this:

```
;WITH myTable AS(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DATE]) AS rn
FROM OriginalTable
)
SELECT this.ID, this.DATE, this.STATUS
FROM myTable this
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable prev ON prev.ID = this.ID and prev.rn = this.rn-1
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable nxt ON nxt.ID = this.ID and nxt.rn = this.rn+1
WHERE NOT ((this.STATUS= 'RESTART' AND prev.STATUS IS NOT NULL)
           OR (COALESCE(nxt.STATUS,'') = 'RESTART'))
```

I was assuming that your DATE column is of type date or datetime, but if it's a string, you should convert it to a date in the ORDER BY portion of the ROW_NUMBER call.

Comment: +1 - This excludes `RESTART` rows if they have an immediately preceding row.  It also excludes rows where the succeeding row is `RESTART`.  Seems to be spot on to me!

Comment: Thanks.  The description wasn't completely clear, but I think we've both inferred the same requirements from the sample data.